# Changing coordinate of point using its WKT and PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geometry, well-known-text

I need to change the position of a box only if it has a common attribute with a point. In my example if the feature `"ID_PARENT"` is the same as `"CODE"`.

```py
box = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('box')[0]
point = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('point')[0]

for bfeat in box.getFeatures():
    for pfeat in point.getFeatures():
        if bfeat['ID_PARENT'] == pfeat['CODE']:
            pfeat.geometry() = bfeat.geometry()
```

Here this code is totally false because I'm assigning a value to a function call but I think it illustrates well what I tried to do which is changing the WKT coordinate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you want to move a box' centroid position to another point if it has a common attribute with the point. I assume `ID_PARENT` and `CODE` are unique values. Use this script:

```py
box_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('box')[0]
point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('point')[0]

dpr = box_layer.dataProvider()

for box in box_layer.getFeatures():
    for point in point_layer.getFeatures():
        if box['ID_PARENT'] == point['CODE']:
            box_as_point = box.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
            point_as_point = point.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
            
            dx = point_as_point.x() - box_as_point.x()
            dy = point_as_point.y() - box_as_point.y()
            geom = box.geometry()
            geom.translate(dx, dy)
            
            dpr.changeGeometryValues({box.id(): geom})
            
            break
```

[image]